# How to set the minimum reload time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an application that performs asynchronous functions

Example:

```
function openTypeNumberComponent(props) {
    setCountryCode(props)
    setSelectCountryView(false)
    setTypeNumberView(true)
}
```

When the function is called, the state is reloaded and other data are displayed
It looks different. Sometimes it works right away and sometimes a little longer

I would like to display an indicator (some animation)

How do you make Indicator work for at least 1 second? If I need more time then more and if it is done faster it should last at least 1 second anyway

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: each async function adds to counter and on success - reduces counter:

```
var loaderIndex = 0;

function toggleLoader(i) {
    loaderIndex += i;

    if (loaderIndex > 0) {
        loader.show();
    } else {
        loader.hide();
    }
}

function fooFunction() {
    toggleLoader(1);

    $.ajax({
        finnaly: () => toggleLoader(-1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a function executes after 1 second, if you want to do that after 1 second, but I recommend that you add a callback function that executes after loading the game and hides the loading spinner, because maybe your game will load after more than 1 second, consider low connection debit of some of your users, and high debit also, so it takes less than a second.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector(".fa-spinner").style.display = "none";
}, 1000);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size: 30px"></i>
```